# How to Host Separate Flutter Web App and Landing Page on Firebase Hosting?

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-hosting

I am currently developing a project where I need to host a Flutter web app alongside a static landing page, both under the same domain using Firebase Hosting. The structure I'm aiming for is as follows:

The landing page should be served from `mysite.com/index.html`.
The Flutter web app should be accessible at `mysite.com/game/index.html`.
I'm encountering difficulties in configuring Firebase Hosting to support this structure. Specifically, I am looking for assistance in two areas:

**Directory Structure**: How should I organize the directory structure within my Flutter project to properly accommodate both the static landing page and the Flutter web app?

**Firebase Hosting Configuration**: How do I configure the firebase.json file to correctly handle URL rewrites for this setup? I'm looking to ensure that:

Navigating to `mysite.com` serves the landing page.
Navigating to `mysite.com/game` serves the Flutter web app.
If anyone has experience with a similar setup or can offer examples of firebase.json configurations that work for this scenario, I would greatly appreciate your input. Additionally, insights into best practices for organizing the project directory in such cases would also be beneficial.

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "source": ".",
    "headers": [
      {
        "source": "**/*.@(eot|otf|ttf|ttc|woff|font.css)",
        "headers": [
          {
            "key": "Access-Control-Allow-Origin",
            "value": "*"
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "/game/**",
        "destination": "/game/index.html"
      },
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ],

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firebase Hosting shouldn't require any specific configuration for this.

Just move (or direct) the output from your Flutter build into the `game` subdirectory under your Firebase project directory, and run `firebase deploy`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is there a straightforward method to automatically direct my Flutter web build output to a specific subfolder under the 'public' directory for Firebase Hosting, without manually moving the 'build/web' folder each time?

Comment: From reading the docs on [building a Flutter web app](https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/web) it seems that the path can't be changes, but you can of course write a batch file/shell script to copy the files over to where you want them.